# D3js svg how to make an arrow shape that is not closed

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a directed network graph. This [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8043434) on d3 nicely illustrates how to accomplish my task but I wonder how to make the arrows open triangles rather than closed ones. In the example:

```
omitted.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

It seems to me that the original author uses `<path>` and `<path>` makes closed shapes even though it's **not** `M0,-5L10,0L0,5Z` ending with a `Z`. I wonder how I can eliminate the line from `0,5` to `0,-5`?

Comment: What's an open triangle?

Comment: More to the point what's an open filled triangle?

Comment: By "open" I mean not making the shape “closed". In other words, if you look at the end of an arrow an "Isosceles", an "open" one is an Isosceles without the bottom line.

Comment: You did notice that the arrows in your example are filled with a colour didn't you? Draw two lines that touch at one vertex and colour the space in between the lines and what do you get?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm quite new to d3 and svg so I still need some time to understand how this example works. But I get what you mean and I'm trying in a jsfiddle now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They **are** open, it's just that they are all filled with a colour so you can't see that they are open. If you drew a stroke in a different colour to the fill it would be rather more apparent.

Comment: Good catch! This answers my confusion perfectly :P